# Nhibernate mapping without id

Tags: c#, nhibernate-mapping

I have a Parameter table in my sql server db. This table contains 20 or so fields, but only **ONE** record. This table will always contain one record, and also contains no Id or key field.

How do you map this with NHibernate?

Answer (score 2):

What about creating a column that would always hold 1 (or whatever other value). I believe that if you want to be able to update your columns you will need an ID.